# How to implement a click or touch listner on ListView to get application activity

Tags: android

I have non-system application list in list view and i am trying to implement a onClicklistener or OnTouchListner on this view.But cant able to do that.
here is the code

```
List<ApplicationInfo> list = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
for (int n=0;n<list.size();n++) {
 if((list.get(n).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)!=1)
 {
 results.add(list.get(n).loadLabel(pm).toString());
 Log.w("Installed Applications", list.get(n).loadLabel(pm).toString());
 }

}


lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
```

where result is the arraylist and lView is the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a click listener for an item, you should use [AdapterView.setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) if you want to perform something on each item. Otherwise, you can add a AdapaterView.setOnClickListener which will do something each time is clicked regardless of the item selected.